# Bar chart with ID indicator

Tags: r, charts, data-visualization

My data:

```
structure(list(Id = c(8378563200, 5577150313, 4702921684, 4388161847, 
7086361926, 6962181067, 4445114986, 5553957443, 4319703577, 1503960366, 
2026352035, 3977333714, 6117666160, 8792009665, 4020332650, 2347167796
), total_steps = c(8377719, 6477458, 7174818, 7710336, 6972600, 
9412809, 4163404, 8276690, 5858684, 9390475, 4832044, 9227036, 
3551544, 806370, 562272, 2570310), total_sleeps = c(427769, 336960, 
349432, 285324, 337125, 430528, 334335, 445408, 384183, 279217, 
439363, 246660, 241304, 189515, 86645, 120636), total_calories = c(3302554, 
2620514, 2482164, 2205930, 1909368, 1904733, 1897616, 1802526, 
1642368, 1407725, 1337280, 1271480, 1139616, 853605, 591680, 
551730)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I am looking for a way to build a bar chart in R Languages with the Id indicator on top of each bar chart showing the calories burned, total steps and sleeps. Or  I can try to facet them with 24 respondents indicating the calories burned, total steps and sleep. Please tell me which way is better or consult me on a better way to visualize it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

1. Bring you data in lang format with `pivot_longer`
2. transform `Id` and `name` to factor type
3. use `ggplot`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -Id
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Id = factor(Id),
         name=factor(name, levels = c("total_steps", "total_sleeps", "total_calories"))) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Id, y=value, fill=name, label=value))+
  geom_col(position=position_stack()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value,family = "serif"), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  theme_bw()
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Id = c(8378563200, 5577150313, 4702921684, 4388161847, 
7086361926, 6962181067, 4445114986, 5553957443, 4319703577, 1503960366, 
2026352035, 3977333714, 6117666160, 8792009665, 4020332650, 2347167796
), total_steps = c(8377719, 6477458, 7174818, 7710336, 6972600, 
9412809, 4163404, 8276690, 5858684, 9390475, 4832044, 9227036, 
3551544, 806370, 562272, 2570310), total_sleeps = c(427769, 336960, 
349432, 285324, 337125, 430528, 334335, 445408, 384183, 279217, 
439363, 246660, 241304, 189515, 86645, 120636), total_calories = c(3302554, 
2620514, 2482164, 2205930, 1909368, 1904733, 1897616, 1802526, 
1642368, 1407725, 1337280, 1271480, 1139616, 853605, 591680, 
551730)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi TarJae, It is perfect. However, can you explain to me why do I need to transform it into a factor? Besides, If I want to add an indicator (Id) on top of each bar and categorize the Id bar Desc and Ascd order, how can I possibly do it? Thank you very much and I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Working with factors do facilitate things like adding levels, reordering etc... In your case `fct_reorder` from `forcats` package is to use to sort the stacked bars. Using `geom_label` will let you add an id to each stacked bar. Try by yourself and if you fail please start a new question. In my experience this is the best way!

Comment: You are a beast-man, I will post my result once I am done :D

Comment: ```{r}  I Tried this and many different way to sort it such as barplot, arrange, reorder but I haven't found any way yet. Do you have any way to work with this. I was struggling all day yesterday. i am very near to finish this project :D
  user_burned %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Id, y=value, fct_reoder(y=value), fill=name))+
  geom_col(position=position_stack()) + 
  theme_bw()
```